# How can I create a drop down list from a state array?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently trying to render a drop down list within react that will display a list of times.  The user should be able to select a specific value and that value will get updated within the state via onChange().  My issue is that I'm trying to use select, but my drop down list is not showing anything when I click on it.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

This is what I have currently

myfile.js

```js
export default class MyClass extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {

    times: ["1:00", "2:00", "3:00"]

    }
}

RenderList(){
 let tempArray = [];
   let times = this.state.times;

        for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++){
           tempArray.push(<option>{times[i]}</option>)
        }

        return tempArray
}

return (
<div
  <select>{this.RenderList()}</select>
</div>
);

}
```

I kind of expected to see a list of times in the drop down list once it was rendered, but the list is null.

Comment: `i < myArray`, you're comparing a number to an Array, it should be `i < myArray.length`

Comment: @EmileBergeron just updated it and gives me an error: cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: If so, without a [mcve], we can't help.

Comment: @EmileBergeron just updated the exact file you should be able to reproduce it now

Comment: You were only missing the `render` function for it to render correctly. But [German's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57417738/1218980) is the best approach here, with the `onChange` handler as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? You need map to render the options, I hope this helps!

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      times: ["1:00", "2:00", "3:00"]
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    const {times} = this.state;
    return (
      <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
         {times.map(time => {
           return (
             <option value={time}> {time} </option>
           )
         })}
    </select>
    )
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: if times is part of my state and I try to access it by doing this.state.times.map I get the error: cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Oh this is because I'm using react hooks!, are yo familiar with hooks? I can change this to a class component if you'd like to. or I can explain what hooks are ;)

Comment: Sorry not familiar with react hooks.  Yes if you could change it to a class component that would be great.

Comment: I changed it ! let me know if yo have any questions! I hope it makes sense

Comment: Still gives me the same error: cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: can I see your code? because this.state.times is defined so it should work

Comment: you need this.state inside constructor like ``` this.state = {} ```  like i have in my example, since you initialize data in the constructor.

Comment: you need the this keyword

Comment: You can actually leave out the constructor all the way and just declare `state = {}` directly in the class

Comment: @German I forgot that i'm using this.state={} and it still comes up with the same error

Comment: ok, you should also avoid push, I believe using map is better approach.  Take a look at my example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactpracticejs

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the push?

Comment: I believe that your solution should work but for whatever reason i'm still getting the same error with your exact code in my file

Comment: @Michael Great!! no problem man! if you have more questions let me know! what was the issue ?

Comment: For sure will do.  It was just a minor typo on my end when I was changing things.

Answer (score -1):

I think I would do it this way.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class ComponentName extends Component{
    state = {
        myArray: ["1:00", "2:00", "3:00"]}
    }


     render() {
         return (
             <select>
                 {this.state.myArray.map(optn => (
                     <option>{optn}</option>
                 ))}
             </select>
         )
     }

     export default ComponentName
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Did you mean <select>{this.RenderList().map(optn) => {<option>{optn}</option>}</select> ?

Comment: You can leave out the `{}` if you just return from an arrow function but you may need to wrap it in `()` when you return a jsx element or an object.

Comment: But I actually realized that you are not updating your state in the `RenderList` function so you can just map on your `myArray` and delete your `RenderList` function. (I'm updating my answer now)

Comment: Nothing appears in the drop down list

Comment: Did you try with the updated one? I just updated again.

Comment: You still have syntax errors within your code, and its hard for me to understand what is missing from your answer.

Comment: You are right I misplaced the closing `)` I fixed it now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: still giving me an error: cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: Loos like there is something missing with your component setup, can you post the whole component in the question?

Comment: I just updated my answer to show a full component. Hope this is more helpful.

Comment: still gives me the same error.  Does react not allow you to map string arrays??

Comment: Did you copy my entire component? can you post what your current component looks like?